# Need To Convert these lines from text file into Valid json to extract each entity from it

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, file, parsing

Below are the actual lines from my file.
It has about 22K such lines in it.

I want to read each line from the file and want to convert it into a valid json to fetch each attribute from it.

***** Lines from the File *****

```
Gi: ACAT1#<>#Ti: Best Director#<>#Bp: 0#<>#Vt: award#<>#Xt: prize_normalized#<>#Cp: 0
Gi: ACAT10#<>#Ti: Best Screenplay#<>#Bp: 0#<>#Vt: award#<>#Xt: prize_normalized#<>#Cp: 0
Gi: ACAT11#<>#Ti: Best Score#<>#Bp: 0#<>#Vt: award#<>#Xt: prize_normalized#<>#Cp: 0
```

---

From the text file (`'test.txt'`) containing these files, i want to read through each line and get the Values of attributes like `"Ti" , "Gi", "Vt" ...`

I believe those attributes can be easily fetched if I am able to convert each line into `json`.

As as now, i enclosed each line with flower braces `'{}'`.
And then replaced the delimiter `'#<>#'` with `" , "`

Now each line looks something like below.
********After Enclosing in braces and replacing with `","` *********

```
{Gi: ACAT1,Ti: Best Director,Bp: 0,Vt: award,Xt: prize_normalized,Cp: 0}
{Gi: ACAT10,Ti: Best Screenplay,Bp: 0,Vt: award,Xt: prize_normalized,Cp: 0}
{Gi: ACAT11,Ti: Best Score,Bp: 0,Vt: award,Xt: prize_normalized,Cp: 0}
```

---

But still this each line is not a valid json as the objects are not String.

So, When i iterate through each line and try to load the contents of `json` , it throws error, as obviously this is not a Valid `json` without proper String.

******Below is the code******

```
import json

with open("test.txt") as f:
     for line in f:
         a=json.loads(line)
         b=a.get('Vt')
         print(b)
```

This will throw error

So Could you please help me in converting each line from the text into a Valid `json`, So that i can parse through it easily?

*******Expected format of each line***********

```
{"Gi": "ACAT1","Ti": "Best Director","Bp": 0,"Vt": "award","Xt": "prize_normalized","Cp": 0}
{"Gi": "ACAT10","Ti": "Best Screenplay","Bp": 0,"Vt": "award","Xt": "prize_normalized","Cp": 0}
{"Gi": "ACAT11","Ti": "Best Score","Bp": 0,"Vt": "award","Xt": "prize_normalized","Cp": 0}
```

---

If you think converting each line into `json` is not better option, please suggest whatever you feel is the best.

Your Response is highly appreciated.
Regards,

Comment: Replace `#<>#` with `", "`, `:` with `": "`, start of line with `{"` and end of line with `"}`.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: I believe those attributes can be easily fetched if I am able to convert each line into `json`.

You want it to be of type `dict`.

```
import io

DATA = """Gi: ACAT1#<>#Ti: Best Director#<>#Bp: 0#<>#Vt: award#<>#Xt: prize_normalized#<>#Cp: 0
Gi: ACAT10#<>#Ti: Best Screenplay#<>#Bp: 0#<>#Vt: award#<>#Xt: prize_normalized#<>#Cp: 0
Gi: ACAT11#<>#Ti: Best Score#<>#Bp: 0#<>#Vt: award#<>#Xt: prize_normalized#<>#Cp: 0"""

for line in io.StringIO(DATA):
    record = {}
    for k, v in (item.split(': ') for item in line.strip().split('#<>#')):
        try:
            record[k] = int(v)
        except ValueError:
            record[k] = v

    #print(record)
    print('Vt:{}, Bp:{}'.format(record.get('Vt'), record.get('Bp')))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> Vt:award, Bp:0
> Vt:award, Bp:0
> Vt:award, Bp:0
> ```

Comment: I think you can pass generator into `dict()`, no needed to create list. Also list with 2 items (which `str.split()` return) will work, it's not necessary to convert it into tuple.